# Check smsc type of batch and submits it to the proper queue

Tags: java

Here, the for loop loops over a arraylist and checks smsc type of batch and submits it to the proper queue.

Is there a way to rewrite this piece of code in a better way?  Is there any way to eliminate the if/else?

```
for (Batch batch : input.getBatches()){
ArrayList<Messages> arrSentsms = batch.getlist();
String smsc =batch.getSmsc();
    if (smsc.equals("v")) {
            SubmitToQueueV.sendJMSMessage(arrSentsms, priority);
        } else if (smsc.equals("s")) {

            SubmitToQueueS.sendJMSMessage(arrSentsms, priority);
        } else if (smsc.equals("fake1")) {

            SubmitToQueueFake.sendJMSMessage(arrSentsms, priority);
        } else if (smsc.equals("con")) {

            SubmitToQueueCon.sendJMSMessage(arrSentsms, priority);

        } else if (smsc.equals("ce")) {

            SubmitToQueueCEcns.sendJMSMessage(arrSentsms, priority);

        } else if (smsc.equals("cli")) {

            SubmitToxQueueCli.sendJMSMessage(arrSentsms, priority);

        } else if (smsc.equals("pel")) {
            SubmitTQueuePel.sendJMSMessage(arrSentsms, priority);

        } else {
            LOG.debug("smsc" + " smsc not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are those `Submit*.sendJMSMessage()` methods, `static` or actually instance ones on poorly named variables?

Comment: @h.j.k. isn't that ultimately irrelevant? The solution for the codesmell is the same :)

Comment: @Vogel612 it determines if the mapping is done against an instance or a method reference.

Comment: @h.j.k. they are static methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you have (or can easily extract) an interface JMSQueue for this answer.
That's not really an unreasonable assumption I'd say, if you need help with that just drop me a note.

You're using the wrong tool here. What you have is a "mapping" between a string and a certain JMS-Queue.
Let's put that into code:

```
private Map<String, JMSQueue> queues = new HashMap<>();

// [...]
for (Batch batch : input.getBatches()) {
    JMSQueue responsibleQueue = queues.get(batch.getSmsc());
    if (responsibleQueue == null) {
        // queue not found. Log or whatever and then do the next batch
        continue; 
    }
    responsibleQueue.sendJMSMessage(batch.getList(), priority);
}
```

Note that I've done some small changes on your code:

- Respect indentation and whitespace around operators. Your IDE can help you with that.
- Avoid unnecessary variables. They only make it harder to understand the code. Don't have everything inlined, but exercise care when creating variables.
- Respect the naming conventions (talking about `getlist`)

Comment: This will be more efficient that the switch statement.

Comment: Hi.. i think this is nice option also will using an interface improve the performance?

Answer (score 2):

#### Naming

`Batch.getlist()` can be renamed as `getList()` to follow the `camelCase` naming convention.

`arrSentsms` can probably be renamed to better reflect what it actually refer to... is it just `messages`?

Types are usually given in the singular form, so `Messages` looks a bit out-of-place too. What does it contain to represent multiple messages anyways?

#### Interfaces over implementations

If possible, it's suggested to change the return type of `Batch.getList()` to the `List` interface, instead of the `ArrayList` implementation. This is because callers on this method should not need to know they are using the implementation, just that they have an object *adhering to the interface*.

#### Java 8

Since your `Submit*.sendJMSMessage()` methods are `static`, the 'mapping' between `Batch.getSmsc()` and them can be expressed nicely in Java 8 as [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Assuming `priority`'s type is a simple `int`/`Integer`:

```
private static Map<String, BiConsumer<List<Messages>, Integer>> CONSUMERS = getConsumers();

private static Map<String, BiConsumer<List<Messages>, Integer>> getConsumers() {
    Map<String, BiConsumer<List<Messages>, Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("v", SubmitToQueueV::sendJMSMessage);
    map.put("s", SubmitToQueueS::sendJMSMessage);
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

Each possible option for `Batch.getSmsc()` is mapped to a [`BiConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) with the method argument types used by your `static` methods.

You can then apply some basic mapping on the output to become a `Map<String, List<List<Messages>>`:

```
input.getBatches().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Batch::getSmsc,
                Collectors.mapping(Batch::getList, Collectors.toList())))
// further processing...
```

This uses the [`groupingBy(Function, Collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) `Collector` to map `Batch.getSmsc()` (used as a method reference here too) to a `List` of the `List<Messages>` returned by `Batch.getList()`, by [`mapping(Function, Collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) them [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--).

With this `Map`, we can then iterate through its entries to call your sending methods via [`Map.forEach(BiConsumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-).

Putting it altogether:

```
input.getBatches().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Batch::getSmsc,
                Collectors.mapping(Batch::getList, Collectors.toList())))
        .forEach((k, v) -> {
            BiConsumer<List<Messages>, Integer> consumer = CONSUMERS.get(k);
            if (consumer == null) {
                LOG.debug("smsc [" + smsc + "] not found.");
            } else {
                v.forEach(m -> consumer.accept(m, priority));
            }
        });
```

If a `consumer` is not found, you can use your debug statement, else you can have the `BiConsumer` returned [`accept()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html#accept-T-U-) each `List<Messages>` and the given `priority`.

#### `static` methods

On a final note, you may even want to reconsider the design of your `static` methods for sending JMS messages. Assuming the only differences between them is a queue name, you can have just one method that takes in the queue name as a method argument, so that you don't have to manage similar code across many classes.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html), that will at least be easier to extend and maintain.

The switch statement will clean up the code by removing all of the else if statements. The code doesn't need enclosing blocks for multiple statements. The switch statement only shows one condition although it tests for all the conditions listed by the cases.

To add a new condition rather than adding a new `else if` statement all you need to add is a new case statement. The `break;` statement is needed in this
particular case to move on to the next iteration of the loop. It is possible to flow through multiple cases if the `break;` statement is not there. The link above shows an example of flowing through multiple cases without a `break;` statement as well as the normal mode.

Switch statements are common to C, C++, VBA and some other languages as well as Java.

Here is the code re-written using a switch statement.

```
for (Batch batch : input.getBatches()){
    ArrayList<Messages> arrSentsms = batch.getlist();
    String smsc =batch.getSmsc();

    switch(smsc)
    {
        case "v" :
            SubmitToQueueV.sendJMSMessage(arrSentsms, priority);
            break;

        case  "s" :
            SubmitToQueueS.sendJMSMessage(arrSentsms, priority);
            break;

        case "fake1" :
            SubmitToQueueFake.sendJMSMessage(arrSentsms, priority);
            break;

        case "con" :
            SubmitToQueueCon.sendJMSMessage(arrSentsms, priority);
            break;

        case "ce" :
            SubmitToQueueCEcns.sendJMSMessage(arrSentsms, priority);
            break;

        case "cli" :
            SubmitToxQueueCli.sendJMSMessage(arrSentsms, priority);
            break;

        case "pel" :
            SubmitTQueuePel.sendJMSMessage(arrSentsms, priority);
            break;

        default:
            LOG.debug("smsc" + " smsc not found");
            break;
    }
}
```